# using letters in a Switch statement

Tags: c, compiler-errors, char, switch-statement, warnings

I try to use Y and N in a switch statement but when I try to compile it I got an error what say "  error: statement requires expression of integer type ('char [0]' invalid)
                switch (xx) {
"

i also got a warning "  warning: incompatible pointer to integer conversion passing 'char [1]' to parameter of type 'char' [-Wint-conversion]
                                sucheZeichen(name, imya); "

```
int main() {

char name[200];

printf("Please tell me your name:");
fflush(stdin);
scanf("%s", name);
printf("%s has %i letters\n", name, langeZeichne(name));

// frage

int end = 0;
char xx[0];

char imya[1];

do {
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("would you like to count a letter in %s (Y / N)?\n", name);
    scanf("%c", xx);

    switch (xx) {
        case "Y":
            printf("Please enter a letter\n");
            scanf("%s", imya);
            sucheZeichen(name, imya);
            break;
        case "N":
            printf("Have a nice Day!");
            end = 0;
            break;
        default:
            printf("Wrong input\n");
            break;

    }
}while (end==0);
```

}

Comment: Use single quotes. But you have some more issues around, such as array of zero size, string with no space for `\0`, `fflush(stdin)` and such...

Comment: You're not using letters (characters).  You're using strings.

Comment: BTW: `incompatible pointer to integer conversion passing`: this warning is should almost always be considered as an error.

Comment: Your compiler should have warned you. Listen to that, and if you don't see anything, turn up the error reporting.

Comment: `char xx[0];` is wrong.  (You can't have an array of 0 things -- what would it mean?)  `scanf("%c", xx);` is wrong.  (Well, it matches your wrong declaration of `xx`, sort of, but it's not what you want.)  If you want `xx` to be a character, then declare it as one: `char xx`.  And then when you use it in your `switch` statement, the case labels must be characters, too: `'Y'`, `'N'`.

Comment: when i del [0] and just do char xx; I got "Terminated due to signal: SEGMENTATION FAULT (11)" and 3 new warnings

warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing 'char' to parameter of type 'const char *'; take the address with & [-Wint-conversion]

warning: incompatible pointer to integer conversion passing 'char [1]' to parameter of type 'char'

Comment: @DomenicWolf I understand.  But the way to fix those errors is not to randomly change things until the warnings go away.  You have to *understand* what the warnings mean.  Your other problem is that you are using `scanf`, which despite its popularity is nearly impossible to use correctly.  You want `scanf("%c", &xx)`.  That `&` is super important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, if you want to read a letter into `xx` don't use an array, and **definitly** not an array of size 0.

Second, your `switch` receive an `char[]` instead of a `char`.

Next, in the `case`s use chars instead of strings.

Moreover, according to the information in the question, `sucheZeichen` gets a `char` as a second parameter (or an `int`) so the same problem with `xx` as an array apply for `imya` as well.

Also, I added `\n` to the `scanf` so it won't read the newline character.

Your code should like like:

```
int main() {

    char name[200];

    printf("Please tell me your name:");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%s", name);
    printf("%s has %i letters\n", name, langeZeichne(name));

    // frage

    int end = 0;
    char xx;

    char imya;

    do {
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("would you like to count a letter in %s (Y / N)?\n", name);
        scanf("%c\n", &xx);

        switch (xx) {
            case 'Y':
                printf("Please enter a letter\n");
                scanf("%c\n", &imya);
                sucheZeichen(name, imya);
                break;
            case 'N':
                printf("Have a nice Day!");
                end = 0;
                break;
            default:
                printf("Wrong input\n");
                break;

        }
    }while (end==0);

}
```